# VB.Net: removing an item from a structure

Tags: vb.net, data-structures

I've got a VB.Net structure containing a bunch of data about an object.  Objects are added to this structure through the course of the day and tend to have a finite life so, over time, my structure ends up containing objects that have expired.

During their lifetime some of their properties change so I have a dictionary so that I can easily find the appropriate object should I need to update it.

However, when an object expires I'd like to remove it from the structure.  I can remove it from the dictionary but can't figure out how to remove it from the structure.

Here's my structure:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Main()
    End Sub

    Public Structure ObjectList
        Public hash As String
        Public xPosition As String
        Public yPosition As String
        Public zPosition As String
        Public speed As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal _hash As String, ByVal _xposition As String, ByVal _yposition As String, ByVal _zposition As String, ByVal _speed As String)
            hash = _hash
            xPosition = _xposition
            yPosition = _yposition
            zPosition = _zposition
            speed = _speed
        End Sub
    End Structure

    Sub Main()
        Dim Tracking As ObjectList

        Dim dict_Tracking As New Dictionary(Of String, ObjectList)

        ' Define a new object
        Tracking.hash = "4D010AEF"
        Tracking.xPosition = "3.5"
        Tracking.yPosition = "7.2"
        Tracking.zPosition = "8.1"
        Tracking.speed = "16.2"

        ' Add hash to dictionary so that we can find it easily without searching entire dictionary
        dict_Tracking.Add(Tracking.hash, Tracking)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is there an easy way to remove an object from the structure ?  I'd rather avoid creating an empty copy and then copying across the active ones before destroying the old one if I can.

Comment: Your structure isn't actually a list or collection. It's just information about a single object. So unless you haven't posted some of the code all you need to do is remove your object from the dictionary with `dict_tracking.Remove(Tracking.hash)`

Comment: Hmm, I'm already using the Remove method as you suggest but the memory that my program takes keeps on growing as new objects come in so it appears not be actually removing them unless there's something else going on that I've missed.  Is there any easy way to inspect the contents of the structure so that I can see what's in it to confirm either way ?

Comment: A structure is very similar to a class. They aren't collections. So your one only contains 5 strings. Use the debugger and look at what is in the dict_tracking collection. Your memory leak is elsewhere in your application. Try using the jetbrains dotMemory trial evaluation or post the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks, I've create a conditional breakpoint that fires when the 40th object is added to my structure but I can only inspect the current one rather than all of them.  I'll take a look at dotMemory though in case that highlights an issue.  Thanks

Comment: It appears that the issue was partly caused by VB.Net creating an object for each & every string that is read in from my data stream.  In my example above, if the hash '4D010AEF' is read in 5000 times then 5000 string objects are created for it.  Using String.Intern() has reduced this significantly but I'm still getting heavy memory usage.  Even though it's creating far fewer string objects if I let the application run for a few hours it gradually takes more & more memory as there's no obvious way to tell it that I no longer need a reference to a hash that expired hours ago. Baffled !

Comment: How are you determining that you have a memory leak?  Are you using a memory profiler?  Removing an object from a dictionary, will not free up its memory.  The garbage collector will eventually come along and free all unreachable objects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to.

Your structure is basically just a container with some data about your object. When your object is removed from the dictionary, this container is removed with it. So there is no need to manually remove data from it.

For the mandatory car analogy:
You don't need to empty the ashtray of your car when you take your car to be destroyed in one of those gigantic presses.